# Mark row in dataframe that contains a any column = NAN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

I have a dataframe that contains 3 columns

Some rows contain a column that has a NaN Value.

I have used `checkfornan=df.isnull()` to generate a dataframe (checkfornan) that I can used to locate individual values a NaN.

But what I would like to do is add another column in my original dataframe (df) say 'isNaN' and assign a value of True into that column if any other value in the same row is Nan, or False if no values in same column are NaN.

Being new to Dataframe, I am not sure how I use the output from `df.isnull()` dataframe to combine it with my original dataframe to achieve this?

Any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check if *any* column is a NaN, create a new column:

```
df['isNaN'] = df.isnull().any(axis=1)
```